# Invalid Foreign Key Relationship when retrieving from class

Tags: apex, visualforce, relationships

I've a parent object (Product) and a child (Inventory). I'm trying to retrieve the value of the child object from a class that I've created.

```
public class DisplayProducts {
    private Product__c products;

public DisplayProducts(Product__c item) {
    this.products = item;

}

// Properties for use in the Visualforce view
public String name {
    get { return products.Name; }
}

public String colour {
//error here 
        get { return  products.Inventorys__r.Colour__c; }
//products.Inventorys__r[0].Colour__c; --> only retrive the first element, dosen't seems to work
    }

public class Product {

public List<DisplayProducts> getProducts() {

        if(products == null) {
            products = new List<DisplayProducts>();

            for(Product__c item : [Select ProductID__c,Name, Price__c, (SELECT Inventory__c.Size__c, Inventory__c.Colour__c,  Inventory__c.Quantity__c FROM Product__c.Inventorys__r) 
                From Product__c WHERE ProductID__c = :prodID]) {

                products.add(new DisplayProducts(item));
            }

        }    
    return products;
}

}
```

However I keep getting a compile error: invalid FK relationship. Why is that so?

When I retrieve the object using SOQL statement it works perfectly.

```
Select Name,  (SELECT Inventory__c.Colour__c FROM Product__c.Inventorys__r)  From Product__c];
```

but why it doesn't work in the Display Class? Thank you.

Comment: You can't "go through relation" with . (dot) in Apex. Have you tried building a query in the code to select the data needed from the Inventorys object based on the Id of the product

Comment: @MihaiNeagoe Hi, I've tried building a query based on the SOQL found on mu question. But how do I retrieve through the class that Ive created above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

products.Inventorys__r will return list of child records .

The return type of your method is a string .Hence you may need to return a list of child records .

If you need  the child array you can use something like below

```
  public List< Inventory__c> colour {
        get { return  products.Inventorys__r;}//return list of Inventory records and this would be list data type
   }
```

Comment: thanks for you reply. I've tried your method. However I got an error message List index out of bounds: 0 .

Comment: You have no child data hence the issue.Add an if clause to check size of the list.

Comment: sorry for the silly question. Got it!

Comment: Can i check with you, currently my list has multiple items. How do i loop through products.ProductInventorys__r.Colour__c;? Coz your code only retrieve the first element from the item. Thanks!

Comment: For(Inventory__c i:products.inventorys){
   system.debug(i);
}

Comment: still having issue with the above question. Have tried your solution but I still can't retrieve the Inventory items via the Display class. I've edited my codes. Hope you could help.

Comment: @taradyn Have edited answer and should help.You can use apex:repeat,apex:datatable or apex:pageblocktable to display the result set